# Astrologers' star pattern in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Unable to print star pattern in python using Jupyter notebook. May be the issue with Jupyter Notebook or else. Please help and highlight the mistake.

```
print("Astrologer's star")
print("How many row of star you want?")
n = int(input())
print("Please input 1 if you want stars in ascending form or \nprint 0 if you want stars in descending form")
oneORzero = bool(int(input()))

if oneORzero == True:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print("*")
    print("")
    
else:
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print("*")
    print("")
```

[image: This is the image which system was showing.]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print()` prints a whole line every time it is called, unless specified otherwise. You can use the parameter `end=""` to clarify you don't want it to add a new line.

You would then also need to print a newline character at the end of the inner for-loop. This could look like the following:

```py
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        print("*", end="")
    print("")
```

Notice, that `print("")` is indented one more level.

Comment: Thanks Zubler. The error highlight by you is rectified in answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it out. The problem is with all print function under for loop.
I mentioned my correct code as here under.

```
print("Astrologer's star")
print("How many row of star you want?")
n = int(input())
print("Please input 1 if you want stars in ascending form or \nprint 0 if you want stars in descending form")
oneORzero = bool(int(input()))

if oneORzero == True:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print("*", end="")
        print("")
    
else:
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            print("*", end="")
        print("")
```